# A representing matrix of a linear transformation which acts on a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

$$
\text{Let }V\text{ be a subspace of }\mathbb{R}^3\text{ with dimension 2,} \\
\text{Let }A=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 1 \\
 2 & 0 & -1 \\
 -3 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix} \\
\text{Let }S \text{ be a linear transformation }S:V\to V, \text{such that } S\underline{x} = A\underline{x}.
$$

Is there a basis B of $V$, such that $A = \left[S\right]_B$ ?

An answer stated that each representing matrix of $S$ is of order $2\times 2$, while A is $3\times 3$.

Though I think that each representing matrix of $S$ is of order $\mathbf{3}\times 2$, because that:
$$
\left[S\right]_B = \begin{bmatrix} | & | \\
[S(v1)]_B & [S(v2)]_B \\
| & | \\
\end{bmatrix} \in Mat_{3\times 2}
$$
While $B = (v1,v2)$.

So is it $2\times 2$ or $3\times 2$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $[S]_B$ will indeed be a $2\times 2$ matrix. Recall that if $V$ is a 2-dimensional subspace, it doesn't matter how many coordinates you have in each vector, a basis $B$ of $V$ only consists of two vectors, say $B = \{b_1,b_2\}$, so any element of $V$ is of the form $\alpha b_1 + \gamma b_2$.

Hence, to study the linear map $S$ we have to write $S(b_1)$ and $S(b_2)$ in terms of the basis $B$, i.e., as linear combinations of $b_1$ and $b_2$. If $S(b_1) = \alpha_1b_1 + \alpha_2b_2$ and $S(b_2) = \gamma_1b_1 + \gamma_2b_2$, then
$$ [S]_B = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 & \beta_1 \\ \alpha_2 & \beta_2 \end{pmatrix}. $$

It is easy to get a little confused about what dimension is what, but the important thing here is that $S$ is a map from $V$ to $V$. If you wanted to consider a map $T:V\to \mathbb{R}^3$ you would then have a $2\times 3$ matrix as you would need to write the images in terms of a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$, which has dimension 3.